# How to make the result from continous script a callable object for another

Tags: python

I am trying to run one script that will continuously get new data from a GPS module and store it in a Queue for another script to make calls to it.

I am using this script as gps_data.py:

```
running = None
gpsd = None

os.system('clear') #clear the terminal (optional)

class GpsPoller(threading.Thread):

    QUEUE_MAX_SIZE = 50

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        global gpsd
        gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE) #starting the stream of info
        self.current_value = None
        global running
        running = True #setting the thread running to true
        self.queue = Queue.Queue(maxsize=self.QUEUE_MAX_SIZE)

    def run(self):
        while running:
            gpsinfo = gpsd.next() #this will continue to loop and grab EACH set$
            # Here I'm just populating the queue with the return of gpsd.next()$
            # you can choose what you specifically want to populate it with.
            # like gpsinfo = [gpsd.fix.latitude, gpsd.fix.longitude]
            self.queue.put_nowait(gpsinfo) #add the gpsinfo to the queue for ot$
```

I am trying to get that data into another_script.py

Here's my attempt:

folder structure:

```
manage.py
hud/
    another_script.py
    gps_data.py
```

another_script.py

```
from gps_data import GpsPoller
import Queue

g = GpsPoller()
g.start()
run = True
while run:
    try:
        # Get item for the GpsPoller queue
        gpsinfo = g.queue.get(True, 1) # blocking with a timeout of 1 sec
        print 'gpsinfo:', gpsinfo
        g.task_done() # tell the queue that the task is done (you are done usin$
    except Queue.Empty:
        print 'Queue is Empty'
        run = False
```

I am getting the error `AttributeError: 'GpsPoller' object has no attribute 'task_done'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html). You can have your GpsPoller, which is running in its own thread, populate a queue. In your another_script.py thread, you can read that queue and if there are items in that queue, print the item.

Since I do not have the gps script/hw I cannot test the code for you, but it would be something similar to this:

In your gps_data.py:

```
import os
from gps import *
from time import *
import time
import threading
import Queue

gpsd = None #seting the global variable

os.system('clear') #clear the terminal (optional)

class GpsPoller(threading.Thread):

    QUEUE_MAX_SIZE = 50

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        global gpsd #bring it in scope
        gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE) #starting the stream of info
        self.current_value = None
        self.running = True #setting the thread running to true
        self.queue = Queue.Queue(maxsize=self.QUEUE_MAX_SIZE)

    def run(self):
        global gpsd
        while self.running:
            gpsinfo = gpsd.next() #this will continue to loop and grab EACH set of gpsd info to clear the buffer
            # Here I'm just populating the queue with the return of gpsd.next(), 
            # you can choose what you specifically want to populate it with.
            # like gpsinfo = [gpsd.fix.latitude, gpsd.fix.longitude]
            self.queue.put_nowait(gpsinfo) #add the gpsinfo to the queue for others to read
```

And the other_script.py would look something like this:

```
import gps_data.GpsPoller
import Queue

g = GpsPoller()
g.start()
run = True
while run:
    try:
        # Get item for the GpsPoller queue
        gpsinfo = g.queue.get(True, 1) # blocking with a timeout of 1 sec
        print 'gpsinfo:', gpsinfo
        g.queue.task_done() # tell the queue that the task is done (you are done using gpsinfo)
    except Queue.Empty:
        print 'Queue is Empty'
        run = False
```

Comment: On a side note, I would not use `global gpsd` unless I have a reason to. I would make it an attribute of your `GpsPoller` class. `self.gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE)`.

Comment: Also it is bad practice to do `from <module> import *` it is better to do `from <module> import <attributes needed>`. The best and recommended way is `import <module>` and use the attribute as `<module>.<attribute>`

Comment: I updated my OP with your suggestions. I couldn't make it work without global vars... I am now getting a new error `AttributeError: 'GpsPoller' object has no attribute 'task_done'`

Comment: Thank you... I am leaning towards sqlite3 as a solution to what I am trying to do however I learned a lot about threads and queues because of your recommendation...cool stuff and thank you!